# How Do I Pull More Metadata components in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I've installed eclipse and the Force.com IDE Plugin. When I created a new project and added my credentials and security token, it brings me to the next page of where I choose initial projects components. However, when I look at mine, it is just blank screen, so I could not pull the workflow components which is what I need.

Does any have any idea on why this is showing up as blank to me and what I need to do to add workflow components once I have created the project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Force.com perspective -> Right click on your Project -> Force.com->Add/Remove Metadata Components -> Add/Remove.

Answer (score 1):

After you have added a `Force.com Nature` you can modify your `package.xml` contents. My typical package would include: `Apex Classes`, `Apex Triggers`, `Custom Labels`, `VisualForce Components`, `VisualForce Pages`, and `Static Resources`. Below I have also added `Flows`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexClass</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexComponent</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexPage</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexTrigger</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomLabel</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>StaticResource</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Flow</name>
    </types>
    <version>34.0</version>
</Package>
```

Alternatively you can right click on your top level folder and click on `Add/Remove Metadata Components`. Make sure `Flows` is checked.

Answer (score 0):

Ah yes ..

> Does any have any idea on why this is showing up as blank to me and what I need to do to add workflow components once I have created the project?

I have noticed this myself and discovered that for large orgs, it can take some time (minutes) for the Eclipse IDE to render the dialog with available components.  I've stared at the blank dialog and thought I had messed up my setup. Patience was the key.

Answer (score -2):

If you are talking about the initial project contents dialog box, which defaults to having most Apex items selected (Apex Classes, Triggers, VF Pages, etc.) and allows you to select different components or "None", the issue can be resolved by re-sizing the dialog box.

Selecting the right side of the window and dragging it slightly outward works for me. Or try expanding the dialog box to be full-screen then back.